# Como passar dados da base de dados para combobox?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Queria colocar alguns dados da base de dados numa combobox mas não estou a conseguir, acho que o problema será a ligação à base de dados mas não sei o que estará errado, podem-me ajudar?

```
<?php
...
$dbconn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname)or die("Failed to connect to database:" . mysqli_error($dbconn));

$query = "SELECT nome FROM Medicos";
$data = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
$result = mysqli_num_rows($data);       

?>
  <form name="medicos" method="post" action="">
  <label for="">Selecione um m&eacute;dico</label>
  <select>
  <option>Selecione...</option>

<?php while($prod = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
   echo '<option value="'.$prod['nome'].'">'.$prod['nome'].'</option>';
   }
?>    
</select>
```

Comment: Qual é o problema? Dá algum erro? Se sim, edite a pergunta e adicione a mensagem. Se não, o resultado é diferente do esperado? Se sim, descreva qual foi o resultado obtido e qual era o esperado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça o seu while na variável `$data` pois é ela que fez a execução da Query

```
<?php

...
$dbconn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname)or die("Failed to connect to database:" . mysqli_error($dbconn));

$query = "SELECT nome FROM Medicos";
$data = mysqli_query($dbconn, $query);
$result = mysqli_num_rows($data);       

?>
  <form name="medicos" method="post" action="">
  <label for="">Selecione um m&eacute;dico</label>
  <select>
  <option>Selecione...</option>

<?php while($prod = $data->fetch_assoc()) { 
   echo '<option value="'.$prod['nome'].'">'.$prod['nome'].'</option>';
   }
?>    
</select>
```

Comment: se em vez de ser para uma combobox for para uma textbox, basta substituir toda a parte do select por um input type text?

Comment: isso e no name coloque o colchetes para simbolizar um vetor, exemplo: '<input type="text" value="'.$valor_db.'"  name="nome[]"/>'